# Can't get Jquery code to work on click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a calendar that is pulling dates and times from an API online. When it pulls the times, it displays them in a `<ul>` and `<li>` setup as shown below:

[image]

Here is the PHP code that is used to parse the time and create the List Items:

```
foreach($decoded as $times){    
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', $times->time);
    $time = $dateTime->format('h:i A');

     $eventListHTML .= '<li id='.$times->time.' class="available_times">'.$time.'</li><br>';
}
```

I also have Jquery that is supposed to, when one of the times List Items is clicked, slide the div that contains the calendar up, then reveal the next div by sliding down. Here is the code for that:

```
   $(".acuity_times").click(function(){

    $("#calendar_div").slideUp(1000,function(){
       $("#marketing_div").slideDown(1000);
    });
});
```

Here are the two div's that are being referenced in the Jquery:

```
<div id="calendar_div">
<script>
$("#calendar_div").hide(0);
</script>
    <?php echo getCalender(); ?>
</div>
<div id="marketing_div">
<script>
$("#marketing_div").hide(0);
</script>
    <?php echo chooseMarketing(); ?>
</div>
```

What I want it to do eventually is, when I click the available time on the calendar, it will take that time that is set in the ID from the PHP and save it for scheduling an appointment later on, but I haven't yet implemented that part, I'm just trying to get the sliding action to work. Currently, it doesn't do anything when I click the List Item.

Comment: Are you actually interleaving your jQuery code like that?

Comment: maybe use `style="display:none;"` to hide junk instead of peppering jquery all over tarnation

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did try the style="display:none;" before and it didn't work, but now it does for some reason, might have just been cached or something. That still doesn't solve my original question though.

Comment: Not sure if that is copy/paste error, but, you are missing:  }); in your jQuery... With it fixed, code works what is supposed to do: https://jsfiddle.net/kxqtL0nu/  P.S. slideUp doesn't have too much sense, div is already hidden?

Comment: @sinisake Yeah, it's a copy/paste error, I will go ahead and update my question to show the proper code. Also, there is previous Jquery code that slides it down from a previous div when something else is selected there. I am doing it so that only one thing is shown at a time.

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', '.available_times', function(){     
          $("#calendar_div").slideUp(1000,function(){
           $("#marketing_div").slideDown(1000);
       }); });`

Comment: @bos570 Awesome, that was what I was looking for, thank you for the help.

Comment: @EricBrown np. When you dynamically add items to the DOM jquery events don't register as they can't find the specified selector.

Comment: @bos570 Good to know. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Update your PHP and add a value attribute that takes the time:

```
foreach($decoded as $times){    
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', $times->time);
    $time = $dateTime->format('h:i A');

    $eventListHTML .= '<li id='.$times->time.' value='.$times->time.'  class="available_times">'.$time.'</li><br>';
}
```

Update your jQuery code to bind the click event on the `li` elements:

```
$(".available_times").on('click', function() {
    var time = $(this).val();
    $("#calendar_div").slideUp(1000, function() {
        $("#marketing_div").slideDown(1000);
    });
});
```